# jenkins exectue shell docker in slave node without sudo

Tags: docker, jenkins, master-slave

I`m using jenkins and slave node(ssh connect).

I want to exectue shell.

```
docker ps
```

this is error

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

so this slave node connect to ssh (jenkins connect user = ssh connect users) after exec command

```
docker ps
```

normal operation... 
ssh connection and jenkins slave node(ssh connection) different??
why?? jenkins error???? help me...

Answer (score 0):

Docker Daemon is not started on slave, this is a docker deployment issue. Some tips are [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-is-the-docker-daemon-running-on-this-host/8925/8). Please make sure to first manually tryout `docker info` and `docker ps` on slave machine to ensure proper docker functioning.